# React-router - how to use route params in onEnter?

Tags: react-router

I want to do a fetch using the onEnter callback, but I don't know how to read a URL param in the Route component.
I have this Route

```
<Route path="book/:bookId" component={BookContainer} onEnter={onBookLoad()}/>
```

I want to use the `bookId` from path as function parameter for `onBookLoad()`. Is it possible?

Comment: onEnter no longer in react-router https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768620/onenter-not-called-in-react-router

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nevermind, it was trivial.

```
<Route path="book/:bookId" component={BookContainer} onEnter={onBookLoad}/>

export function onBookLoad(nextState) {
 console.log(nextState.params.bookId);
 //do stuff with the param
}
```

Comment: Do you mean bookId, not surveyId?