# onEnter not called in React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Ok, I'm fed up trying.
The `onEnter` method doesn't work. Any idea why is that?

```
// Authentication "before" filter
function requireAuth(nextState, replace){
  console.log("called"); // => Is not triggered at all 
  if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/front'
    })
  }
}

// Render the app
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <App>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/front" component={Front} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} onEnter={requireAuth} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} onEnter={requireAuth} />
            <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </App>
      </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("lf-app")
```

Edit:

The method is executed when I call `onEnter={requireAuth()}`, but obviously that is not the purpose, and I also won't get the desired parameters.

Comment: Which react-router version are you using?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`onEnter` no longer exists on `react-router-4`. You should use `<Route render={ ... } />` to get your desired functionality. I believe [`Redirect`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) example has your specific scenario. I modified it below to match yours.

```
<Route exact path="/home" render={() => (
  isLoggedIn() ? (
    <Redirect to="/front"/>
  ) : (
    <Home />
  )
)}/>
```

Comment: Although, I noticed today that this doesn't actually render the component of the new url to which is redirected. Is this desired behaviour? Doesn't seem very logical...

Comment: @KimGysen no, this is not the default behaviour. If you are using `Switch` component then `Redirect` should be rendered as expected. However, if you are not using `Switch`, `Redirect` will not be rendered (as I assume was your use case).

Comment: @Deividas Karžinauskas  i see there is a small issue in here , what if the user <Redirect to="/front"/> ? front content should load after authencated right ?

Comment: What's happen if isLoggedIn is Async function?

Comment: How does this work if you are using Redux? how do you access isLoggedIn, if it is in your state's tree?

Comment: One way is to import your store and access the `getState()` method which will return the current state of the store:

    `import store from '../store/store.index'; // or wherever your initialized store is exported`
    
    `const { getState } = store;`  
     
    `const isLoggedIn = getState().app.isLoggedIn;  // Adjust according to your state tree`

Comment: works, but now Home will not have "history" in its props. I don't understand why. It would normally have, if Route was defined with "component={Home}" rather than a render.

Comment: @EgoSlayer in case of a [**Promisified**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) isLoggedIn
`render={ () => {
  isLoggedIn().then( res => {
return res ? (
    <Redirect to="/front"/>
  ) : (
    <Home />
  )}) }}`

Comment: @Smily Thank you.

Comment: @Smily How would that work? The render callback isn't actually returning anything.

Comment: @Smily Tested and promises don't work with `render` (had to see if React was adding any magic to enable this)

Answer (score 34):

From react-router-v4 `onEnter`, `onUpdate`, and `onLeave` is removed,
according the documentation on [migrating from v2/v3 to v4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md#on-properties):

> **`on*` properties**
>    React Router v3 provides `onEnter`, `onUpdate`, and `onLeave`
>   methods. These were essentially recreating React's lifecycle methods.
>
> With v4, you should use the lifecycle methods of the component
>   rendered by a `<Route>`. Instead of `onEnter`, you would use
>   `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`. Where you would use `onUpdate`,
>   you can use `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillUpdate` (or possibly
>   `componentWillReceiveProps`). `onLeave` can be replaced with
>   `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: ComponentWillMount is deprecated: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html ComponentDidMount is better choice.

Answer (score 1):

For `react-router-6` the `Redirect` component has been replaced with [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate).

Below `userState` will be either null or populated depending upon if user is logged in or not, can be your Redux state for example.

```
<Route path="/protectedRoute"
            element={userState ? <protectedComponent/> : <Navigate to="/login"/>}/>
```