# Redirect doesn't render component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

This is a follow-up of the question:
[onEnter not called in React-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768620/onenter-not-called-in-react-router)

The following code correctly performs a redirect, but doesn't actually render the component related to the redirection url.
Below is my code, a small adaptation to the code given in the previous question.

```
// Authentication "before" filter
function requireAuth(){
  if(isLoggedIn())
    return <Home />
  else
    return <Redirect to="/front"/>
}

// Render the app
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <App>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/front" component={Front} />
            <Route path="/home" render={requireAuth} />
            <Route exact path="/" render={requireAuth} />
            <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </App>
      </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("lf-app")
)
```

When refreshing the browser after the redirection, the page is correctly displayed.

I would expect the rendering to work but it doesn't... Is this a bug or desired behaviour?

History:

```
... 
import {createBrowserHistory}           from "history";

// Init sagaMiddleware
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(
    appReducers,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store);
```

Comment: How's your `history` setup?

Comment: @HazardouS See update. History v^4.6.0

Comment: Could you compare the values of the `location` prop in your components with the history.location value, after the redirect? If they are not in sync, I'd recommend removing the store syncing part temporarily and try once.

Comment: I had code like this working with the router-v4 alpha, but in the beta and the stable, it no longer works for me either.

Comment: Are you using `connect()` in your <App /> or something else?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, any solutions?

Comment: Maybe it's caused by this? I can see you're using store provider
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671