# React router v4 onUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have recently updated to react router version 4. In the previous version I was using the `onUpdate` call back to trigger a function to make the page scroll to the top when the route has been changed.

It appears that `onUpdate` has been deprecated and I cannot find anywhere in the docs what it has been replaced with.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

```
const handlePageChange = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};  

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router onUpdate={handlePageChange} history={browserHistory}>
            <Redirect from="/" to="/music" />
            {routes}
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4278 :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-every-transition

Answer (score 3):

"onUpdate" is depreciated. You can use "onEnter" property in "Routes".

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} >
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/contact-us" component={ContactUs} onEnter={handlePageChange}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Also need to modify your "handlePageChange" function as below:

```
const handlePageChange = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
        history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
    }
}
```

Comment: `onEnter` no longer exists in v4. Use `render` instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42769225/3498950

Answer (score 1):

@Alireza's answer was in the right direction, but it's not quite complete.

To be able to access the router in using [React's Context API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), the component both has to be a child of the Router, and it should define the `contextTypes` property:

```js
static contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object
};
```

That will make sure that the Router is attached to that component.

Furthermore, you can not (or no longer?) `subscribe` to the router. However, you *can* attach a listener to the History:

```js
this.context.router.history.listen(handlePageChange)
```

You'll probably want to do that in the component's `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to scroll the page when your page component mounts:

```
class NotFoundView extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  render() {
    var props = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="NotFound">
        <HeaderContainer />

        <h1>Coming Soon!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default NotFoundView;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called `context.router.subscribe` as replacement...

you can use something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  //something like this in your code
  componentDidMount() {
    this.context.router.subscribe(() => {
        console.log("change router");
    })
   }
    render() {
    return <button>hi</button>;
  }
}

export default App;
```