# How to use React-router render()

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have read the [onEnter not called in React-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768620/onenter-not-called-in-react-router)
but I do not know how to fix my problem.
I just want to check the login status and redirect

index.js

```
import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history={hist}>
        <Switch>
          {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
            return <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />;
          })}
        </Switch>
      </Router>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

How to change my code to this?

```
<Route exact path="/home" render={() => (
  isLoggedIn() ? (
    <Redirect to="/front"/>
  ) : (
    <Home />
  )
)}/>
```

Comment: Could you describe your problem more exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You should rather not define this in your index.js.

I would recommend to add another class reference in your index.js and place the logic inside there.