# react-router@5 route `onEnter` method not calling, scrolltoview not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

according to my requirement, when a user click on

`<Link to="/products/shoe#product9">Go to projects and focus id 9</Link>` I would like to show him the product. (hello page) for that I do this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import "./products.scss";
    
const Shoes = React.lazy(() => import("./shoes/shoes.component"));
const Cloths = React.lazy(() => import("./cloths/cloths.component"));
    
function hashScroll() {
  alert("called");
  const { hash } = window.location;
  if (hash !== "") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const id = hash.replace("#", "");
      const element = document.getElementById(id);
      if (element) element.scrollIntoView();
    }, 0);
  }
}
    
export default class Products extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <Link to="/products/shoe">Shoes</Link>
          <Link to="/products/cloths">Cloths</Link>
        </header>
        <h1>Products page</h1>
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/products" to="/products/shoe" />
            <Route path="/products/shoe" onEnter={hashScroll}>
              <Shoes />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/products/cloths">
              <Cloths />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I attached an `onEnter` function to call and scroll, so when there is a `#hash` let it scroll. It's not working at all. Please navigate to `Hello` page, from you click the link to go to products page.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tsx-tantum-ayqnkl?file=products/product.component.tsx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onEnter not called in React-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768620/onenter-not-called-in-react-router)

Comment: just use ComponentDidMount for side effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onEnter` is no longer working in react-router

What you can do is pass a prop to the component

```
<Shoes onEnter={hashScroll} />
```

inside the `Shoes` component execute it on `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    if (this.props.onEnter) {
        this.props.onEnter();
    }        
};
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tsx-tantum-5hwuvd)