# React Router - pass path id to onEnter function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I was previously using React Routers URL params to filter an array of content and return the specific content I wanted (filtered by ID). I have now been supplied with a separate API which means I no longer have to return all content and then filter through it, instead I can make one call and return that specific items data.

To make the call on page load I would need to access the id on the Route onEnter function. Is it possible to use a URL param on this onEnter function, and if not - would firing the dispatch function from the container component be the obvious solution?

```
<Route
  path={'locker/my-content/:id'}
  component={ManageContentPage}
  onEnter={() => { store.dispatch(loadMyContent(// NEED ID HERE)); }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using react-router 4+, then the `onEnter` prop no long exists, and you'll have to use the `render` prop to achieve similar functionality.

#### For react-router < 4

Any function passed to `onEnter` will take `nextState` as its argument. This state object will contain your params

So to access this value, you'd need something like the following:

```
<Route
  path={'locker/my-content/:id'}
  component={ManageContentPage}
  onEnter={(nextState) => { store.dispatch(loadMyContent(nextState.params.id)); }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access URL params through onEnter function's argument `nextState`. Here's an example: [React-router - how to use route params in onEnter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212328/react-router-how-to-use-route-params-in-onenter)